# How to use describe() on multiple CSV file and save into one file with the CSV file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 4 CSV files. I am using `describe()` methods to get the description of all files. The code is working without any error

```
def describe():
        descr = []
        for csv in CSVS:
            dataset_name = csv.stem[: csv.stem.find("_")]
            df = pd.read_csv(csv)
            des = df.groupby("Method").describe().round(2).Col11
            des.name = dataset_name
            descr.append(des.T)
        descr_df = pd.concat(descr)
        return descr_df
```

The output I am getting

```
    Method_1    Method_2    Method_3
Count
mean
Std
min
...
```

My expected output is like the beloow One

```
                  Dataset_1    Dataset_2    Dataset_3
Method_1    Count
            mean
            Std
            min
...
Method_2    Count
            mean
            Std
            min
```

Any kind of suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You need to create multi level column, for each of the dataset summary.

Comment: @Don'tAccept how can I do this?

Comment: Is `method` column name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) concatenates by default along the index, meaning adding new rows. You see to want to concatenate along the columns:

```
descr_df = pd.concat(descr, axis='columns')
```

What’s more, if you concatenate using a dictionary instead of a list, you can specify the keys (or with a list and the `pd.concat(..., keys=[...])` argument):

```
descr = {}
for csv in CSVS:
    # your code to read dataframes and dataset names
    descr[dataset_name] = des.T
descr_df = pd.concat(descr, axis='columns')
```

Now you will probably have `Dataset` / `Method` index levels as columns, and statistics types as indexes. You can move levels from columns to indexes and back with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), and reorder them with [`reorder_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html).

This means your function should probably end with:

```
return descr_df.stack(1).reorder_levels([1, 0])
```

Comment: The code giving the output in this form "Count Method_1" "Count Method_2" "Count Method_3" (row by row) and  "Mean Method_1" "Mean Method_2" "Mean Method_3"

Comment: @Opps_0 Then you want to chain [`.reorder_levels([0, 1])`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) at the end

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but getting the same output like the before. However, I wanted, all summary for method_1 and then all summary for method_2 and so on.

Comment: @Opps_0 my bad − `[0, 1]` is already the order of levels. To reverse them you need `[1, 0]`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes it is working

Answer (score 1):

`stack` each summary and `unstack` level 0 and `stack` again, finally call `.to_frame` and pass the name of the dataframe (the summary belongs to) i.e. the column name you want, and finally reset the column, do this for all the dataframe summary, and finally `outer` merge them, rename the columns as per requirements, and set the index

```py
pd.merge(df1.describe().stack().unstack(0).stack().to_frame('df1').reset_index(),
        df2.describe().stack().unstack(0).stack().to_frame('df2').reset_index(), how='outer')\
.rename(columns={'level_0':'Methods', 'level_1':'Statistics'})\
.set_index(['Methods',  'Statistics'])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
                         df1       df2
Methods Statistics                    
A       count       5.000000  5.000000
        mean        0.521492  0.620648
        std         0.262874  0.373520
        min         0.129904  0.155943
        25%         0.446187  0.273549
        50%         0.512456  0.866164
        75%         0.714380  0.881218
        max         0.804531  0.926368
B       count       5.000000       NaN
        mean        0.641817       NaN
        std         0.163022       NaN
        min         0.474867       NaN
        25%         0.475255       NaN
        50%         0.658282       NaN
        75%         0.791397       NaN
        max         0.809282       NaN
C       count            NaN  5.000000
        mean             NaN  0.735040
        std              NaN  0.194365
        min              NaN  0.470806
        25%              NaN  0.668021
        50%              NaN  0.690349
        75%              NaN  0.877549
        max              NaN  0.968477
```

You have your required structure, you can write it to the file.

**UPDATE:**

For a number of datasets, you can use above logic in a loop, something like this should work:

```py
out = pd.DataFrame(columns=['level_0', 'level_1'])
for i,df in enumerate([df1, df2], 1):
    out =df.describe().stack().unstack(0).stack().to_frame(f'Dataset_{i}').reset_index()\
            .merge(out, how='outer')
out = out.rename(columns={'level_0':'Methods', 'level_1':'Statistics'})\
    .set_index(['Methods', 'Statistics'])
```

Comment: If I have 10 datasets then I have to write 10 lines!

Comment: @Opps_0, see the updated answer, you can use a loop.